# Elastic Search in a complex document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document stated below. I would like to do a search but I could not do it as I lacked the knowledge. Please help. How can I do searches in ElasticSearch in complex aggregates?

My Document

```
{
    "_index": "vehicles",
    "_type": "car",
    "_id": "e16bd474-fa8e-4858-ab6c-3bbb3d0aa603",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
    "Type": {
     "Name": "Mustang"
  }
}
```

}

My Search Query

```
GET _search 
  {
 "query":{
    "filtered": {
       "filter": {
           "term": {
              "Name": "Mustang"
           }
             }
       }

     },
 "from":0,
 "size":10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Standard Analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is being applied to your `Name` field, so the term `Mustang` is being stored in the index as `mustang`. Change your query to use `"Name": "mustang"` and you should get a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the doc with "Name" : "Mustang" you can use

`"query" : {
   "bool" : {
       "must" : {
           "term" : {
               "Name" : "Mustang"
           }
       }
   }
}`

Comment: I was so happy to see the response but nope It did not work. As I suspect this object is an aggregate car and cartype. Car type has a property name. I am trying to search there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. You are using `term` filter which is searching for `Mustang` token in the index, however the standard analyzer is being used so it is actually indexed as `mustang`.
2. You are searching in the wrong field. You should be using nested notation e.g. `Type.Name`

This query should work as expected:

`{"query":{ "filtered": { "filter": {
   "term": { "Type.Name": "mustang" }
 }}}}`